# SPI Signal Integrity

Tags: spi, signal-integrity

A couple of days ago I had an issue where I was unable to read data from an SPI slave. I finally fixed and I'm now able to read data quite well.

However, I found another interesting issue today. If I connect the slave's output directly to the MCU, the data is corrupted. The following picture shows this:

[image]

However, if I put in a series 220 Ohm resistor the data comes in just fine, like so:

[image]

The byte transferred was 11001101. You can see the start and end of the transfer from the two small dips in the waveform. The starting dip is seen near the trigger indicator. These are nowhere to be seen in the corrupted waveform.

The rate of data transfer is not very fast. The clock rate is just 62500 Hz.

What could cause this? And how can I make sure that it does not occur when I finally layout the PCB?

The top waveform is the clock (SCK) and the bottom is MISO.

These waveforms show the ringing in more detail. Again, top waveform is the clock and the bottom is MISO. This picture has the CPLD and MCU connected via 220 Ohm resistor:

[image]

This shows the ringing when the MCU and CPLD are connected directly (no resistor between them). Note that I cannot get to the source pin (in this case, the CPLD's pin) because the CPLD is on a development board and the chip is on a BGA package. I will try and see if the pin can be probed. Also, I forgot to add, I also have a 100 Ohm resistance in series on the SCK like. I needed this to reduce ringing from the MCU on the clock and because its required for the AVR ISP programmer. Otherwise, AVR Studio simply puts out an error. So, on the final PCB layout they are going to be needed.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're probing the right signals?  The first image looks like you're following a clock signal.  Neither appear corrupted.

Comment: Yep. I leave the probe connected and as soon as I connect the MCU directly to the slave, the waveform changes.

Comment: Display the clock, as well.

Comment: @LeonHeller I've updated the question with new images. These show the clock as well.

Comment: Can you label the signals somehow? It looks as though A is SCK and I'm guessing that B is MISO, but it's not clear. It may also be helpful to show the chip select line if you have an additional channel on your scope.

Comment: Are you bit-banging?  Could this be the sinister work of an interrupt firing during your transfer?

Comment: No siree. No interrupts at all. Just pure SPI tranfer.

Comment: Of course you will have all kinds of ringing when you build on one of those awful breadboards.  Is your scope hooked up with the ground wire and alligator clip?  That will show some more ringing.   But if you're going to zoom in and look at the edges, you need to use a tiny ground path. ¶ In my experience, the top trace looks good, like a solid SPI connection.  No amount of signal degradation is going to turn a clear square signal into a different clear signal. You need to look elsewhere for a software bug or wrong connection. ¶ Wrong connections are common on those nylon slabs of trouble...

Comment: I hear you, markrages. I'm very fed up with breadboards but it was the only choice I had. But I'm going to start work on my layout by tomorrow and hopefully have a prototype PCB fabricated soon enough. If nothing else, I've learned how important it is to have the shortest possible signal path. So I'll be placing my MCU next to the CPLDs.

Comment: When probing high speed signals you can use a temporary short ground attached near the tip of the probe to reduce loop area. Here is a good [link](http://www.analog.com/library/analogDialogue/archives/41-03/time_domain.html) that gives tips on this.

Comment: Just so we're clear, the plastic breadboards where you push wires into holes are the problematic ones. I don't think the etched-board ones have nearly these problems.

Comment: BTW, the third screenshot is classic overdamped behavior (edge is too slow), while the fourth is classic underdamped behavior (edge too fast). The fast edge ringing is obviously bad, but the slow edge is bad, too, because it spends too much time near the input's threshold voltage, and a small amount of added noise will result in glitches in the input buffer's output. Schmitt trigger inputs can help this, by adding hysteresis, but are rarely built-in to PLDs or MCUs, and only help if the noise voltage (peak-to-peak) is less than the hysteresis voltage.

Comment: I've found myself here because I'm having the opposite problem. My SPI doesn't work unless I remove some of the 220R resistors I have in the MOSI, CLK and the enable lines. The phenomenon of ringing comes from an LRC circuit. If R is very low and the L and C reactances dominate, the circuit is under-damped and ringing will occur when you have a transition from low to high. Parasitics on your circuit including the the pcb traces themselves provide the L and the C. By increasing the value of R to 220R, you're damping the circuit and the ringing disappears. I don't know what my particular problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When probing, you need to probe the signal where it hits the input pin, and make sure the probe ground is connected to a ground near that pin, so it doesn't hide any ground bounce. It looks to me like you're probing at the output pin, which will hide any ringing.

In the first plot, I see spikes at the signal edges. This tells me that you have some overshoot and possibly potential ringing. The fact that a 220 ohm resistor fixed it is indicative of this as well.

There are three usual solutions to this problem.

The first solution is to use a ferrite bead in series to damp the spike. The ferrite bead will look like a large resistance at high frequencies and a short at low frequencies. It's not the same as an inductor (and a spike usually means you have more than enough inductance in your line).

The second solution is to use a series resistor like you did, but typical values for this resistor are around 22 to 50 ohms, depending on the transmission line impedance, and the resistor must be placed at the source (driver output) end of the line (usually within 0.2 inch, though that may not make any difference at 62.5 kHz). The function of this resistor is to slow down the rising and falling edges of the waveform, damping their high-frequency components. 220 ohms seems like too much resistance to me. You can also use a ferrite bead (or similar EMI filter) with the resistor, usually if your line is part of a cable.

Finally, you might be able to program your driver for a slower edge rate (several nanoseconds instead of one or two), though this is still an unusual feature. This is actually the best solution, and greatly reduces EMI to boot.

Comment: +1 - Good point about the slew rate limiting - IIRC from the last question this was on an FPGA, so it's quite likely there will be an option to program it for slower rise time.

Comment: Hoping that MCU/DSP vendors start putting slew rate control in their chips...

Comment: Thanks Mike. This is on an CPLD and I'll look into reducing the rise/fall time. I hope its possible. However, I need to include the resistance anyway. This is because I program the AVR via ISP and that utilizes the SPI lines as well. The AVR ISP application note suggests to put a small resistance on each SPI line (except SS) otherwise the AVR mkII can't program the MCU. I intend to include a small header on the board for the programmer, so these resistance will be required in anycase.

Comment: Okay, forthat you'll need a resistance of at least 1k or so. The resistances I gave will be too strong for the AVRisp to drive. However, you still want the resistor on the driver end of the wire, or you'll want a buffer on the receive end (so it would be MISO out -> 27 ohm -> long wire -> buffer input, then buffer output -> 1k to 10k resistor -> ISP header -> MISO pin on AVR). And you only need that 1k to 10k resistance on lines that will be driven by devices other than the AVR or the ISP, which is just MISO unless you have other SPI masters on the bus.

Comment: Mike, will a 1K resistance not delay the signal by a large amount? And could you please elaborate on the buffers? If I remember correctly, a buffer will have a very large input impedence and a small output impedence. But what is the function of a buffer in this particular application?

Comment: I've generally used 10k resistors with no problem to weaken the peripheral MISO drive so the AVRisp wins, but that was on the same board, not with long lines, and with about 100 kHz clock rate. So I don't see 1k being a problem. If you want to be sure, calculate the time constant (multiply the sum of the series resistances by the input pin's capacitance; kilohms times picofarads gives nanoseconds); the edge time should be less than two time constants, so see if that's fast enough.

Comment: As for the buffer, that's because of the long line. If you have a 10k resistor at the driver end of a long line, then it looks like the line is being driven by a 10k source impedance, which is pretty weak and is thus sensitive to interference, usually from neighboring signals. If you put the resistor at the receiver (input) end, then you could get a reflection off of it, though that may not be a big issue if the time of flight on the wire is less than half of the edge time.

Comment: The buffer will make this a non-issue; the long line will have a strong drive but not too strong because of the 27 ohm or so source resistor, while the connection from the buffer to the AVR MISO pin will be short enough that a 10k series resistor won't matter. Try it without the buffer first; this may be a non-issue for you. Oh, and adding to the above: the capacitance from the breadboard is added to the input pin's capacitance; this is why those things suck.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not quite sure how it manages to change so drastically from the first signal to the second (I think this is probably what Kevin was thinking) but the most likely problem sounds like a longish line and ringing. You can see some ringing on the first trace (almost 2V on a 3.3V line), which maybe will tell more of a story if you reduce the timebase. This might be causing some strange things to happen like the Rx pin picking up multiple transitions - may be even coupling to other traces and causing issues there.
The resistor will damp the ringing and fix things. The clock rate is not the issue, more the rise time of the signal.
You could shorten the lines (if that's an option), but it's good practice to have a small series resistor anyway.

Comment: Yes, the line is quite long. It's all  on a breadboard for now but I'm going to shift onto a PCB in about two weeks. What resistor values would you recommend? Is this the only to fix ringing? Is there no way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: How long is the line? The breadboard might be contributing to issues, but it's hard to say exactly what's going on from the info. I think it will probably go away when you put it on the PCB, but leaving a series resistor in there (say 20-200 ohms) is a good idea anyway. Have a Google for termination and signal integrity.

Comment: I see you added the clock line in the pics - can you reduce the timebase and post that too? (i.e. "magnify" the intial rise of the signal, e.g. <1us/div) It should show any ringing in much more detail.

Comment: @OliGlasar I have attached the reduced timebase pictures. You were right - lots of ringing!